# Change HTML embed element clicktag url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, embed, clicktag

I have the following embed element where the clicktag is set to www.test.gr so if i click on it i navigate to www.test.gr.

I also have an input field where the user can set the url but when i update the url Firefox still navigates to the old despite i see with inspect that it has changed.

```
<embed style="width: 70px; height: 348px;" src=".." type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
wmode="opaque" allowscriptaccess="always" flashvars="clickTAG=www.test.gr">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: my guess is flash has already bound the `flashvars` value internally. Try replacing the element with new value set

Comment: @charlietfl In Chrome i detach the embed, update the clicktag and append it back and works great! The problem is on firefox where this set of commands does not work.. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Still a problem? Have you thought of using JavaScript to tell the plugin to update the variable.